# Error when working with graphics modules in python?

Tags: python, graphics

When I work with graphics modules such as tkinter, easygui, and graphics.py in a shell(in terminal), I usually get this error:

8 12:37:27 Jasmines-MacBook-Pro.local Python[18090] : kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetWindowTags: Invalid connection

After which the shell is interrupted and I can't enter any more text. What is going on?

OSX 10.7.3, and Python 3.1.1 from python.org.

Comment: Which version of OS X?  Which Python (Apple-supplied, python.org, other)?

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.1 is obsolete and no longer maintained and the python.org OS X installers for it are linked with Tcl/Tk 8.4 which is also obsolete. Suggest installing the latest 64-bit/32-bit version of Python 3.2.x *and* installing the latest ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.5.  There's more information about Python and Tcl/Tk versions on Mac OS X [here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/).